# Which technique is useful for image SEO, when images is coming from CSS?

Tags: seo, google-search, search-engines, tags

Now a days many images display using css like below :

```
<div title="My Logo" class="all_logo mt15">&nbsp;</div>
```

Above `div` will show logo image, But as using CSS for logo instead of `<img>` tag.
So not take the benefits of `alt` tag by SEO point of view.

My question is :

Which technique or method I use for image SEO in this type of image?

I mean, Which technique is useful for image SEO, when images is coming from CSS?

Answer (score 0):

The `title` you mention is the attribute, which is not to be confused with the `<title>` meta tag. And no, it is not taken into account for SEO.

Comment: Can you suggest What technique I use for such images seo?

Comment: For images, the alt attribute is the best, but if you cannot set one, try the figure caption http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_figcaption.asp Hope it helps